How to read choice from input step and use it as an environment variable in Jenkins
I would like to add a choice parameter for the user to choose which version to deploy.
Something like this
stage('User Input') {
    steps {
        input message: 'User input required', ok: 'Release!',
            parameters: [choice(name: 'RELEASE_SCOPE', choices: '2.1\n2.2\n2.3', description: 'What is the release scope?')]
        echo "env: ${env.RELEASE_SCOPE}"
        echo "params: ${params.RELEASE_SCOPE}"
    }

That choice should be populated to docker-compose file.
services:
    bo:
        image: docker-new.tinder.net/bo:{params.RELEASE_SCOPE}

That doesn't work for me. Should I convert that parameter to environment variable?

According to the docs the input step returns the value(s) user enters:

Request that the submitter specify one or more parameter values when approving. If just one parameter is listed, its value will become the value of the input step. If multiple parameters are listed, the return value will be a map keyed by the parameter names.

stage('User Input') {
    steps {
        script {
            def RELEASE_SCOPE = input message: 'User input required', ok: 'Release!',
                parameters: [choice(name: 'RELEASE_SCOPE', choices: '2.1\n2.2\n2.3', description: 'What is the release scope?')]
            echo "Return value: ${RELEASE_SCOPE}"
            env.RELEASE_SCOPE = RELEASE_SCOPE
        }
    }
}

